# Web service returning a large byte array

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am developing a web service that returns a file and the file can be large (> 100 MB), it returns the file as a byte array. Is there some way to return it as a stream so that the client can read the file by chunks from the stream?

Comment: How are you using WCF? If you're using WCF in SOAP mode then you'll hit performance issues (as everything is encoded to XML for the SOAP envelope). I suggest you use a side-channel besides WCF for the transfer of large files.

Comment: @Dai by side-channel you mean to return the file over a HTTP GET action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that I've used is to have the WCF SOAP service return a URL to a WCF-implemented HTTP GET service that can efficiently return the data. We happily return a few gigabytes that way.

If you want to stick with RPC-style WCF services, but don't have to use HTTP, you could use the Net.TCP protocol, which passes large binary data a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't like transfer huge amount of data in WCF, i prefer some other ways, but if you need to use it optimize the channel with MTOM encoding is a goot point.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209(v=vs.110).aspx